# how to run the NBIS software package 'mindtct' in matlab? i mean what should be the input commands?

Tags: image-processing, fingerprint, biometrics

i have been trying all day to run this software but I haven't been able to figure it out how. I have read the manual but it didn't help much. when I type "mindtct -b -ml  " on the MSYS shell, the command line says "mindtct:command not found". If anyone has used it before please help me out.

Comment: 1. What does this have to do with Matlab? 2. mindct is part of the ffpis software package, which you must build and compile. These programs aren't supposed to work out of the box. If you are using MSYS, then you're probably not going about it the right way.

Comment: from the MSYS homepage: `A common misunderstanding is MSYS is "UNIX on Windows", MSYS by itself does not contain a compiler or a C library, therefore does not give the ability to magically port UNIX programs over to Windows nor does it provide any UNIX specific functionality like case-sensitive filenames. Users looking for such functionality should look to Cygwin or Microsoft's Interix instead.`

Comment: 1.> I want to use the text file created by 'mindtct' as an input to the matlab program. 2.>I have installed the complete NBIS package using MSYS as it was recommended in the installation manual. Now I just have to run the mindtct package of it. So, now should I use cygwin or continue with Msys.

Comment: I tried running the command with cygwin also. But I got the same result. Bash says " mindtct: command not found ".

Comment: just out of curiosity, how do you install the application?

Comment: I downloaded the package from the site, and since I am Win-64 bit machine, I had to install msys and mingw before the actual installation. then I just followed the instructions given in the manual. I am trying the same to run the software but it says "command not found".

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `mindtct` is not in your `PATH`.  Add the directory containing the compiled `mindtct` to your `PATH`, or specify the absolute path to `mindtct`.  Then follow in the instructions in the `man` page for how to run `mindtct` to do what you'd like it to do.